# Fetching A Large Number of Sorted Results using cursors performance issue

Tags: solr, solr4

I used cursors to search and export specific documents in solr according https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/pagination-of-results.html#fetching-a-large-number-of-sorted-results-cursors.

We used solr 4.10.3 and isolated read/write via one master node and two slave nodes, the slave node **poll internal is 1 minute**, and optimize the collection weekly by maxSegments=10. And there are about 100,000,000 documents in the collection now.

We encountered search performance now when we fetch A Large Number of **Sorted Results**. Per check, the main bottleneck is **sort**. The search URL is similar like http://192.168.238.133:8080/solr/collection1/select?q=*:*&rows=1000&sort=id+asc&cursorMark=*, it consumed several minutes to return result to client (**Even the result count=0**, NOT just sort the result documents???). When we curl http://192.168.238.133:8080/solr/collection1/select?q=*:*&rows=1000&start=0, we can get results in seconds. When we curl http://192.168.238.133:8080/solr/collection1/select?q=*:*&sort=id+asc&rows=1000&start=0, the performance is poor as cursor query.

BTW, the id schema definition is default:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

How to improve the **sort performance** when "**Fetching A Large Number of Sorted Results**"? Is it helpful if we change the id type from **string** to **long**?

Answer (score 0):

Enable DocValues for id field.

`<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" docValues="true" />`

Unfortunately it enabled by default since solr 6, You need to manually enable it and reindex all data.

Comment: Thx! docValues should be helpful to sort performance, but reindex all data ... except we have no other options. Per test if we increase the polling interval from 1 min to 10 mins, then we have 7~8 mins good sort performance time window.